# How do I setup bonding on Centos 6.x for High Availability?

Tags: ubuntu, centos, high-availability, bonding

My server has two Ethernet ports.  With Bonding I setup two different IP addresses for both.  The hardware is not very new, so I wouldn't expect that the newest versions of these features to work.  The problem is that it doesn't report any problem no matter what level I use.  There is no indication that this server with this switch does not support this or that setting in the configuration.  I believe there are 6 levels, from a course I took.

I guess it helps to know the server model that I am using.  It is an HP Proliant DL365G5.  I did setup bond0 and the main interface and eth0 and eth1 are slaves to that master interface.  I asked someone elsewhere and he said that I need a router that supports high availability.  When I was learning about this it seemed to be more of a function of what the switch inside the server supports.

As an aside, I'm curious, my ISP offers fiber to the building.  So, I can get up to 1Gbps.  I hear some places are getting 2Gbps.  Would I need a 10Gbit switch for those situations?  But then again, if an ISP offers a maximum of 2Gbps coming into the home and you have wireless devices and various other wired connections, are they splitting the total of 2Gbps or by running some things in parallel can I get the full bandwidth on each device?
Thanks,
Bruce

Comment: I've flagged your question as "unclear what you're asking".

Answer (score 1):

What?

I understand that you may be interested in these features. But try to focus on what you want to accomplish.

Your server has TWO gigabit ethernet ports. They're on the motherboard. You don't need bonding. If you want bonding, you can configure one of the various modes available. Some of those modes require switches capable of bonding (mode=4); some don't.

Your question about ISP and bandwidth doesn't quite make sense. Please clarify with your ISP on how they'll deliver service into your facility.